# Lazy ApplicationListener

Tags: spring, events, lazy-initialization

When I add `ApplicationListener` to a class, Spring instantiates the bean eagerly (probably to make sure that the bean gets all the events).

In my case, I have a bean which listens for "CacheFlush" events (i.e. I don't really care how many I might miss).

How do I implement a lazy `ApplicationEvent` listener in Spring 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if what you want to do is possible directly, but one potential solution is to have a separate [Observable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) bean listen for the cache flush events and notify its Observers when one comes in.  Have your lazy bean register with the Observable when it is initialized.